# Key-binding shortcut for Tufte html export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I've perused a few of the org-mode html-export key-binding shortcuts, i.e., ways to just have one key do, e.g., the entire long-winded `C-c C-e h o`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be one fell swoop function like `org-html-export-as-html` to get the whole job done with what I'm using, namely, [ox-tufte](https://github.com/dakrone/ox-tufte). I've located the (probably) germane section

```
(org-export-define-derived-backend 'tufte-html 'html
  :menu-entry
  '(?T "Export to Tufte-HTML"
       ((?T "To temporary buffer"
            (lambda (a s v b) (org-tufte-export-to-buffer a s v)))
        (?t "To file" (lambda (a s v b) (org-tufte-export-to-file a s v)))
        (?o "To file and open"
            (lambda (a s v b)
              (if a (org-tufte-export-to-file t s v)
                (org-open-file (org-tufte-export-to-file nil s v)))))))
  :translate-alist '((footnote-reference . org-tufte-footnote-reference)
                     (src-block . org-tufte-src-block)
                     (link . org-tufte-maybe-margin-note-link)
                     (quote-block . org-tufte-quote-block)
                 (verse-block . org-tufte-verse-block)))
```

but I'm not sure how to put together a custom function to accomplish the key shortcut of `C-c C-e T t` to F9. Any suggestions appreciated. Any suggested tutorial to understand what the above function is doing would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about setting the `async`, `scope`, or `visible-only` options, then you can do something like this:

```el
(defun my/org-tufte-export-direct-to-file ()
   (interactive)
   (org-tufte-export-to-file nil nil nil))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") #'my/org-tufte-export-direct-to-file)
```

i.e. call the function that the `t` key calls when you are in the export dispatcher. `C-c C-e T t` says invoke the export dispatcher (`C-c C-e`) which brings up the menu where you can set some options, but principally where you can select which exporter to use. The `T` then selects the Tufte exporter (I presume - I don't have it installed) and the `t` dispatches to `org-tufte-export-to-file` as shown by the snippet of code you posted.

Another possibility is to define a [keyboard macro, save it and assign it to a key](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html). See the "Keyboard Macros" chapter in the Emacs manual (`C-h i g(emacs)Keyboard macros`).